# solaris 11 zone sysconfig profile for ipmp

Tags: configuration, solaris, ip, profile

How to create sysidcfg profile with ipmp? Let's say we have such network config:

```
root@zone1:~# ipadm
NAME              CLASS/TYPE STATE        UNDER      ADDR
ipmp_bkp          ipmp       ok           --         --
   ipmp_bkp/v4    static     ok           --         10.12.4.177/22
ipmp_prd          ipmp       ok           --         --
   ipmp_prd/v4    static     ok           --         131.123.123.158/24
lo0               loopback   ok           --         --
   lo0/v4         static     ok           --         127.0.0.1/8
net0              ip         ok           ipmp_bkp  --
net1              ip         ok           ipmp_bkp  --
net2              ip         ok           ipmp_prd  --
net3              ip         ok           ipmp_prd  --
```

I can't find examples for this. There is just simple network config:

```
  service version="1" type="service" name="network/install">
    instance enabled="true" name="default">
      property_group type="application" name="install_ipv4_interface">
        propval type="net_address_v4" name="static_address" value="131.123.123.158/24"/>
        propval type="astring" name="name" value="net2/v4"/>
        propval type="astring" name="address_type" value="static"/>
        propval type="net_address_v4" name="default_route" value="131.123.123.1"/>
      /property_group>
    /instance>
  /service>
```

- I have removed "<" sign before each line above, as the xml disappears here if I leave them.

Comment: A while ago I searched for the same and my conclusion is that this can not be done (yet) and that the current best approach is to use a first boot script or create a sample config and copy the `/etc/ipadm/ipadm-DefaultFixed.conf` file directly. Please note that I haven't tested this.

Comment: I might be wrong and it has been a while, but why use **value="net2/v4"**, the interface will be directly the ipmp interface: **value="ipmp_prd"** but I wuold need to test it first actually.

Comment: Could be, but how then define which adapters should be in ipmp_prd group? In my example i have 4 adapters, so 2 of them should be in prd and 2 another in bkp group.